# How does mounted combat interact with the Charger feat?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, actions, mounted-combat

I saw that [someone on Reddit asked about the Charger feat while on a mount](https://www.reddit.com/r/DnD/comments/35bb6h/charger_feat_and_mounted_combat/). I understand that [using Dash with the mount's action isn't counted as you dashing](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/657838517557547009) according to the rules.

However, does the following make sense:

1. I use *my* action to Dash my mount (e.g. spur my mount on, increasing speed by 10 ft (maybe))
2. Now that I am Dashing, I use my bonus action to do the Charger feat attack with a +5 bonus to damage.
3. Use my mount's action to Disengage and leave the enemy's reach.

Would this work?

Answer (score 3):

## No, because the mount acts on a separate turn from yours

[Charger](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/feats/charger) says:

> When you use your action to Dash, you can use a bonus action to make
> one melee weapon attack or to shove a creature.
>
> - If you move at least 10 feet in a straight line immediately before    taking this bonus action, you either gain a +5 bonus to the attack's damage roll (if you chose to make a melee attack and hit) or push the
>   target up to 10 feet away from you (if you chose to shove and you
>   succeed).

#### Step 1

So the basic idea of your **step 1** is perfectly fine. You take the dash action, which is allowed and this means that your movement increases. However, do note that this doesn't affect your mount at all (so no "increasing speed by 10 ft" for example). Also it is good to note here that dash does not modify any speed at all; it simply grants additional movement.

#### Step 2

The problems start around **step 2** however.

Since you have used the dash action, you may now take a bonus action attack against any enemy in range. However, in order to get the +5 bonus damage as well you must first move at least 10 feet in a straight line immediately before taking this bonus attack.

You might think that moving your mount would work, but it does not. This is because a controlled mount seems according to the rules to act on a turn separate from yours. Per [Jeremy Crawford](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/857269467289534464):

> A rider and a controlled mount have separate turns, but they have the same initiative, which means you decide which one goes first.

Thus, you cannot intersperse your and its movement and actions (see [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/117588/28591) for more details on this and the debate surrounding it).

This means that you must end your turn in order to have the mount move towards the opponent. Since it is no longer your turn, you cannot take the bonus attack (bonus actions must be taken on your turn) or the +5 damage (because it is no longer immediately after your dash action).

However, if you dashed then dismounted and moved 10+ feet in a straight line towards an enemy you would definitely be able to get your bonus attack with +5 damage.

Comment: The answer you linked has two answers above which state otherwise, any reason why what the other two answers mentioned doesn't come into play?

Comment: @CuriosMaximus: Good point. I consider the fact that it has been officially ruled that way by Crawford to count for something. Also, the other answers are around 3 years old (before further guidance came out about the issue). However, I do not want to misrepresent the factual nature of the argument so I will edit my answer to make it clearer. You can decide for yourself if you find the argument compelling but it is not within the scope of this answer to address it fully.

Comment: Thanks mate, i has this mental image in my mind about riding into battle with a mount and slamming my full weight of my lance into the enemy then quickly turning away and stepping back ala [fire emblem paladin animation][1]. I'll see what i can do  [1]: http://www.bwdyeti.com/fe/anims/tier2/Paladin-Lance-Crit.gif

Comment: Does the existence of *Ferocious Charger* (Cavalier fighter, XGtE) impact this ruling at all? It has similar conditions (move 10' straight then attack) but has the caveat "...mounted or not". This seems to suggest that a mount replaces your movement to *some* degree for some of these features

Comment: As this is now on the activity page, you might want to address the nature of JC rulings.