# Mounted combat - move, attack, disengage, move. Possible?

Tags: dnd-5e, paladin, mount

Paladin, Mounted Combatant feat, Great axe, riding a Warhorse.

**I'd like to ride 30ft to the mob, bash him with my axe, have the steed disengage, and ride 30ft back.**

Can I do this?

Jeremy seems to be confusing me.  :)

**Spell text:** *"Your steed serves you as a mount, both in combat and out, and you have an instinctive bond with it that allows you to fight as a seamless unit."*

A seamless unit, eh?  Sounds good so far....

**Mounted Combat in PHB:** *"The initiative of a controlled mount changes to match yours when you mount it. It moves as you direct it"*

OK, so it has the same initiative score as me, this isn't looking good...

**Jeremy Tweet from 2017:** *"A rider and a controlled mount have separate turns, but they have the same initiative, which means you decide which one goes first."*

SEPARATE TURNS.  So much for a seamless fighting unit.  Can't ride up, bash, disengage, and ride away.

**Dragon Talk with Jeremy Crawford from 2018:** *"If you control the mount, the creatures initiative changes to your initiative. **You're now acting as a unit.** It still has a turn, but **it's turn OVERLAPS with yours**, it gets its move, **its moving on YOUR turn**, so then far easier for your character to **co-ordinate with the mount**, and it's actions are limited to dodge/dash/disengage. It won't attack. The fact that it can disengage means it can move without opportunity attacks, and the **beauty of it acting on your turn**, with **its turn overlapping with yours**, is that also your movement is still free and your actions are still available. So it's a **movement and action extension for the rider**. A really powerful advantage. Even though it gives up ability to attack, **you gain all this on your turn all this potential movement, and a free dodge/dash/disengage, and a dash means even more movement**."*

This contradicts his earlier tweet, and goes further than the PHB.

What's the actual facts?

Comment: possible dupe? https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/68059/23970

Comment: Honestly didn't see that in my search at the time, frustratingly.    I yield to your superior search-fu. :)

Comment: No worries--you've provided a valuable new signpost to the answers there, which is an unambiguous benefit to the stack. Thanks!