# RAW, can you break up turns between a rider and their controlled mount?

Tags: dnd-5e, mounted-combat, action-economy

Can't seem to find clarification on this, it always just directs me to the Mounted Combat rule.

> **Mounted Combat**
> [...] The initiative of a controlled mount changes to match yours when you mount it. It moves as you direct it, and it has only three action options: Dash, Disengage, and Dodge. A controlled mount can move and act even on the turn that you mount it. [...]

Rules as written, can a rider attack, have the mount take the Disengage action and move, and make another attack on the same turn?

Comment: I’ve closed this as a duplicate as it has been asked before.

Comment: @Thomas Markov I've read that question before posting, but I don't feel like I've found a clear cut answer to my situation still. The accepted answer on that question simply says "Yes" to sharing a turn, but what does sharing a turn mean? There's an unaccepted answer that seems RAW but it's unaccepted so I'm not sure. All in all, can I please just get a clear cut yes/no on breaking up turns, even if it's just in the comments?

Comment: We don’t answer in comments, and the answer I would give to your question here is already posted on the linked dupe, and there seems to be a variety of other perspectives there.

Comment: Which one? Because there are a few contradicting ones

Comment: @field158 Contradicting answers are not unheard of nor disallowed on the Stack; they're actually quite common as there is no guarantee that people will interpret rules in the same way or come to the same (or even similar) conclusions. Tables can look at the evidence the answers provide to help make their own decisions

Comment: Also, this may be a helpful question for you: "[What happens when two creatures actually share the same turn?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/153799)"